# Linking directories in c:\Windows on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I bought a SSD to make it C:. As SSD size is pretty small, I'm trying to reduce the number of files in C:. After running [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/), I found that `4.6G` of space is used for `c:\Windows\Installer`.

Is it safe to link the directory to E: (HDD) after coping all the installer files to e:?

```
mklink /d e:\windows\installer c:\windows\installer
```

Comment: I usually just delete most of the stuff in there. It’s generally not needed unless you are repairing or updating the relevant softwares (which you probably have the installation media for anyway), so it won’t matter (you can point the installer to the media when it asks). The only problem I’ve had when deleting them is that some poorly made installers will require them (or the installation media) in order to *uninstall* (which is ridiculous since you are not *adding* any files).

Comment: @Synetech THat is actually my biggest problem with Windows Installer. I need to make changes to my Visual Studio installation quite often. Therefore I cannot remove the installer files as this then requires me to uninstall the application before i can install or remove new components.

Comment: Ack! You should be using junctions, not symbolic links.

Comment: @Aphelion, maybe you should be figuring out *why* you have to make frequent changes; that’s not normal. Are you simply adding some things that you had not installed?

Comment: @Synetech Well actually recently I had to install service packs. New SDKs. Testing beta versions of software. This is not the issue. Simply a requirement for me, (and for the designers of Windows Installer) is that my packages are available on my machine.

Comment: Each of those service packs, SDKs, and such has its own separate files in `Installer`. Unfortunately they can indeed be intertwined and require the original ones for some reason (why would you need an original file if you are updating?)