# Tools/Tips to reduce the files/directories in C: which is SSD on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I bought a SSD to install it as C: drive on Windows 7. As the SSD size is relatively small, I need to come up with an idea to reduce the files/directories in C:.

What I found is as follows.

1. Run [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to check how the C: is used.
2. Remove the hibernate file (if you don't use it)

   - `powercfg –h off`
   - http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-delete-hibernation-file-hiberfil-sys/
3. Symbolic link files and directories to different drive.

   - I'm not sure if this is safe way to go, I asked another [post](https://superuser.com/questions/301181/linking-directories-in-c-windows-on-windows-7-64bit) to ask about it.
   - `mklink /d e:\windows\installer c:\windows\installer`
4. Install software to E: directory, not C: directory.

   - Create `E:\Program Files`

What other tools or tips do you have?

Comment: Just for reference, what size SSD do you have?

Comment: @Breakthrough : I have two PCs with SSD, one is 80G and the other is 150G.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a utility like [RT7Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) to reduce the actual installation size of Windows.  This is accomplished by removing unnecessary components and features from the operating system, and removing them from the installation itself.

Depending on what you want/need to remove, you can drastically reduce the size of the installed operating system.