# What is the performance impact when user profiles are stored on the HDD instead of a SSD?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

What are the performance benefits like when moving bits and pieces of user profiles to the HDD instead of storing them on the SSD? For brevity, I'm using the following coordinate system:

- (Item, disk drive, expected performance gains)
- (Item, disk drive)

A couple of datapoints may be assumed:

- (Operating system, SSD, great performance gains)
- (Commonly used programs such as Microsoft Office Outlook, SSD, decent gains)
- (Startup programs, SSD, decent gains)

Where would (Full user profile, SSD) go? Would doing (Full user profile, HDD) slow things down a lot? What if I do (My documents folders for each user, SSD) and (rest of user profile, HDD)?

I've found articles online describing the process of creating a single user profile on the HDD. Is there a way to have Windows automatically create profiles on the HDD? What about automatically creating parts of the profile on the HDD (say, the My Documents folder)?

Comment: Your challenge is really the temporary folders, which are stored in `AppData` in your local profile. If that's SSD, it'll aid performance (dramatically, but that's my personal experience).

Comment: Also look at http://superuser.com/q/411080/114909 To save some space on your SSD. It is not usefull to install every OS part on your SSD.

Comment: Ideally I would have everything bar file and application storage on a SSD. On a related note you may be also interested to know you can optimise HDDs by moving system folders/user profiles to the centre of the disk using defrag utils such as [Auslogics](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag/download/).

Comment: Very confusing question... what's the performance like when using a hdd?  Uh... just like people have been experiencing the last 20 years... and with SSD?  If your data (profiles/programs/etc) is stored on the SSD, gosh! it'll probably be faster.